# JMS Serializer deserialize nested objects

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I'm using: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

For deserializing json objects. 
Currently I have this:

```
/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return Customer
 * @throws \Http\Client\Exception
 */
public function get(int $id): Customer
{
    $response = $this->client->get('/customers/' . $id);

    $data = json_encode(json_decode(
        $response->getBody()->getContents()
    )->data->attributes);

    return $this
        ->serializer
        ->deserialize($data, Customer::class, 'json');
}
```

The json that I receive here looks like this:

```
   {
    "data": {
            "type": "customer",
            "id": "4356456",
            "links": {
                    "self":"https:\/\/api.ecurring.com\/customers\/345656"
            },
            "attributes": {
                    "gender": "m",
            "first_name": "Laurens"
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to tell JMS it should automatically start from `data->attributes` instead of doing something dirty like this:

```
 $data = json_encode(json_decode(
            $response->getBody()->getContents()
        )->data->attributes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the exclusion policy.

Read the documentation, it's really helpfull.

[Exclusion policy](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) and [Annotation](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations)